# Close all Java child windows

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

In Java Swing is there a way to find and close all `JDialog`  objects currently being displayed?

I have a large application and there are multiple parts that can call to display a dialog but from one single point I want to be able to detect and close it.

Comment: What is a 'child frame'?  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Don't hit the 'back button' to edit a post!  Use the `edit` link below the question..

Comment: Apologies I have rephrased the question.

Comment: OK, that is now the 3rd time I've removed this noise `Thanks!!!`.  Next time, it will be a down vote.  (And fix that stuck `!` key.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep a reference to each of the dialogs (perhaps in a collection).  When needed, iterate the collection and call `dialog.setVisible(false)`.

As suggested by @mKorbel, you can also use:

```
Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();
```

You'd just need to check for the 'parent' window when iterating the array and closing things.

Comment: Keep a reference to each of the dialogs ?= Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();

Answer (score 2):

The class `Window` which superclasses `JFrame` has the method `getOwnedWindows` which you can use to get an array of all child (owned) `Window`s (including `JFrame`s and `JDialog`s).

```
public class DialogCloser extends JFrame {

    DialogCloser() {

        JButton closeChildren = new JButton("Close All Dialogs");
        JButton openDiag = new JButton("Open New Dialog");

        closeChildren.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Window[] children = getOwnedWindows();
                for (Window win : children) {
                    if (win instanceof JDialog)
                        win.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

        openDiag.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JDialog diag = new JDialog(DialogCloser.this);
                diag.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(openDiag, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(closeChildren, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new DialogCloser();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The question was changed to

> find and close all `JDialog` objects currently being displayed

and I still assume they are all children of the same parent.

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code does the trick:

```
private void closeAllDialogs()
{
    Window[] windows = getWindows();

    for (Window window : windows)
    {
        if (window instanceof JDialog)
        {
            window.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```